# Can't access object properties

Tags: mysql, object, node.js

I am using NodeJS and node-mysql, I've created a DB layer to allow easy integration with other DBs (example MongoDB) for later use. At this point in time, the syntax is essentially the same as MySQL.

I am placing a call to the query object of MySQL, and it's returning the results to my callback function, which I can send to the console with console.log, and it shows the following:

`[ { username: 'test', total: 1 } ]`

Yet, when I try to access the total, it says undefined. Here's my code:

```
db.query("SELECT username, COUNT(user_id) AS total FROM users WHERE username = '" + message.username + "'", function(err, info) {
                                console.log(info);
                                self.sendRequest(client, '{ "command" : "CALLBACK", "result" : ' + info.total + ' }');
                            });
```

when using console.log(info), it returns valid JSON syntax, however I cannot access the total via info.total, as it returns undefined....

Any ideas on why I'm having this issue? If you need to see more code I will be happy to provide it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out;

`info[0].total` returns what I need (d'oh)...